# Convert Bitmap source to bitmap consume much CPU usage

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, bitmap, emgucv

I am using kinect!!I get a frame and then I convert it to bitmap in order to use Emgucv to convert frame in grayscale then convert bitmap to bitmpa source in order to show in window!I am usign C# visual studio WPF!But my program consume much CPU usage and in case the video is frozen for seconds!!I guess that is the conversion bitmpa source to bitmap and viceverse

```
byte[] colorData = null;
WriteableBitmap colorImageBitmap = null;

void myKinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{

    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {

        if (colorFrame == null) return;

        if (colorData == null)
            colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];

        colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);

            if (colorImageBitmap == null)
            {
                this.colorImageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
                    colorFrame.Width,
                    colorFrame.Height,
                    96,  // DpiX
                    96,  // DpiY
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32,
                    null);
            }

            this.colorImageBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height),
                colorData, // video data
                colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel, // stride,
                0   // offset into the array - start at 0
                );


            Image<Gray, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Gray, byte>(BitmapFromSource(colorImageBitmap));
            kinectVideo.Source = ToBitmapSource(My_Image);


    }
}



private System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapFromSource(BitmapSource bitmapsource)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap;
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);

    }
    return bitmap;

}

 [DllImport("gdi32")]
private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);


 public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

        BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            ptr,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
        return bs;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Emgucv to do the greyscaling...which means you have to create a GDI+ Bitmap (System.Drawing.Bitmap) pass it to Emgucv, then convert it back from the GDI+ Bitmap to a BitmapSource, you could use `FormatConvertedBitmap` to keep it in the WPF world.

```
void myKinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        if (colorFrame == null) return;

        if (colorData == null)
            colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];

        colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);

        if (colorImageBitmap == null)
        {
            this.colorImageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
                colorFrame.Width,
                colorFrame.Height,
                96,  // DpiX
                96,  // DpiY
                PixelFormats.Bgr32,
                null);
        }

        this.colorImageBitmap.WritePixels(
            new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height),
            colorData, // video data
            colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel, // stride,
            0   // offset into the array - start at 0
            );

        kinectVideo.Source = new FormatConvertedBitmap(colorImageBitmap, PixelFormats.Gray32Float, null, 0);
    }
}
```

- http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/wpf-image-format-conversion-including.html

Another option is to use a pixel shader that applies a greyscale effect on your "kinectVideo" element (which is presumably an `Image` element to display the frame).

- http://bursjootech.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/grayscale-effect-pixel-shader-effect-in.html